# problems synchronizing icloud database

Tags: ios, core-data, gps, icloud

I'm getting several errors, that are not blocking, in this piece of code:

```
    [psc lock];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                           configuration:nil
                                     URL:localStore
                                 options:options
                                   error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    [psc unlock];
```

Something like the following ( note: at the end of the process, the data seem correctly synchronized , no exception is thrown and error is nil, but however the synchronization takes some time); the error are of two kinds, at the beginning it seems a file ( or more ) is missing and then it says something about data integrity ( some foreign keys that are not satisfied ), maybe the two problems are related ?

Is this a normal situation ?

( btw, the app is in store, https://itunes.apple.com/app/id582749801 , it memorizes tracks from gps and make them available to other devices, tracks may contain much data, 2 records for second )

( sorry for the long log, i have cut it a bit, however it may be useful to understand what is happening )

```
2012-12-14 11:18:25.489 CloudGPSTracker[9303:907] -[PFUbiquityTransactionLog loadPlistAtLocation:withError:](485): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Error reading the log file at location: (null)
userInfo: (null), local error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256 - The item failed to download.)" UserInfo=0x1ddf3ee0 {NSURL=file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/542E2269-592C-4CCA-AA47-A783C78DE466.1.cdt, NSUnderlyingError=0x1ddf3e50 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)", NSDescription=The item failed to download.}
userInfo: {
    NSDescription = "The item failed to download.";
    NSURL = "file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/542E2269-592C-4CCA-AA47-A783C78DE466.1.cdt";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=UBErrorDomain Code=0 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)\"";
}
2012-12-14 11:18:25.491 CloudGPSTracker[9303:907] -[PFUbiquityTransactionLog loadContents:](290): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Error encountered while trying to load the comparison metadata for transaction log: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x1f083450>
    transactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1f005420>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/542E2269-592C-4CCA-AA47-A783C78DE466.1.cdt
    transactionNumber: (null)

Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134302 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134302.)" UserInfo=0x1f2c1ae0 {reason=Error reading the log file at location: (null)
userInfo: (null), local error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256 - The item failed to download.)" UserInfo=0x1ddf3ee0 {NSURL=file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/542E2269-592C-4CCA-AA47-A783C78DE466.1.cdt, NSUnderlyingError=0x1ddf3e50 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)", NSDescription=The item failed to download.}
userInfo: {
    NSDescription = "The item failed to download.";
    NSURL = "file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/542E2269-592C-4CCA-AA47-A783C78DE466.1.cdt";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=UBErrorDomain Code=0 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)\"";
}}
userInfo: {
    reason = "Error reading the log file at location: (null)\nuserInfo: (null), local error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 256 - The item failed to download.)\" UserInfo=0x1ddf3ee0 {NSURL=file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/542E2269-592C-4CCA-AA47-A783C78DE466.1.cdt, NSUnderlyingError=0x1ddf3e50 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)\", NSDescription=The item failed to download.}\nuserInfo: {\n    NSDescription = \"The item failed to download.\";\n    NSURL = \"file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/542E2269-592C-4CCA-AA47-A783C78DE466.1.cdt\";\n    NSUnderlyingError = \"Error Domain=UBErrorDomain Code=0 \\\"The operation couldn\\U2019t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)\\\"\";\n}";
}
2012-12-14 11:18:25.495 CloudGPSTracker[9303:907] -[_PFUbiquityRecordsImporter createSortedOperationsArrayForLogLocationsInContext:isFirstImport:](256): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Error loading comparison metadata for transaction log: (null)
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134302 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134302.)" UserInfo=0x1f2c1ae0 {reason=Error reading the log file at location: (null)
userInfo: (null), local error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256 - The item failed to download.)" UserInfo=0x1ddf3ee0 {NSURL=file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/542E2269-592C-4CCA-AA47-A783C78DE466.1.cdt, NSUnderlyingError=0x1ddf3e50 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)", NSDescription=The item failed to download.}
userInfo: {
    NSDescription = "The item failed to download.";
    NSURL = "file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/542E2269-592C-4CCA-AA47-A783C78DE466.1.cdt";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=UBErrorDomain Code=0 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)\"";
}}
 User Info: {
    reason = "Error reading the log file at location: (null)\nuserInfo: (null), local error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 256 - The item failed to download.)\" UserInfo=0x1ddf3ee0 {NSURL=file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/542E2269-592C-4CCA-AA47-A783C78DE466.1.cdt, NSUnderlyingError=0x1ddf3e50 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)\", NSDescription=The item failed to download.}\nuserInfo: {\n    NSDescription = \"The item failed to download.\";\n    NSURL = \"file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/542E2269-592C-4CCA-AA47-A783C78DE466.1.cdt\";\n    NSUnderlyingError = \"Error Domain=UBErrorDomain Code=0 \\\"The operation couldn\\U2019t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)\\\"\";\n}";
}
2012-12-14 11:20:10.991 CloudGPSTracker[9303:907] -[PFUbiquityTransactionLog loadPlistAtLocation:withError:](485): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Error reading the log file at location: (null)
userInfo: (null), local error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256 - The item failed to download.)" UserInfo=0x1f50b7e0 {NSURL=file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8EEB401B-05C5-4221-AEA3-EC377BB51CAB.1.cdt, NSUnderlyingError=0x1f50b850 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)", NSDescription=The item failed to download.}
userInfo: {
    NSDescription = "The item failed to download.";
    NSURL = "file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8EEB401B-05C5-4221-AEA3-EC377BB51CAB.1.cdt";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=UBErrorDomain Code=0 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)\"";
}
2012-12-14 11:20:10.993 CloudGPSTracker[9303:907] -[PFUbiquityTransactionLog loadContents:](290): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Error encountered while trying to load the comparison metadata for transaction log: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x1f50f490>
    transactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1f18f940>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8EEB401B-05C5-4221-AEA3-EC377BB51CAB.1.cdt
    transactionNumber: (null)

Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134302 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134302.)" UserInfo=0x1f5106f0 {reason=Error reading the log file at location: (null)
userInfo: (null), local error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256 - The item failed to download.)" UserInfo=0x1f50b7e0 {NSURL=file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8EEB401B-05C5-4221-AEA3-EC377BB51CAB.1.cdt, NSUnderlyingError=0x1f50b850 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)", NSDescription=The item failed to download.}
userInfo: {
    NSDescription = "The item failed to download.";
    NSURL = "file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8EEB401B-05C5-4221-AEA3-EC377BB51CAB.1.cdt";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=UBErrorDomain Code=0 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)\"";
}}
userInfo: {
    reason = "Error reading the log file at location: (null)\nuserInfo: (null), local error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 256 - The item failed to download.)\" UserInfo=0x1f50b7e0 {NSURL=file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8EEB401B-05C5-4221-AEA3-EC377BB51CAB.1.cdt, NSUnderlyingError=0x1f50b850 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)\", NSDescription=The item failed to download.}\nuserInfo: {\n    NSDescription = \"The item failed to download.\";\n    NSURL = \"file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8EEB401B-05C5-4221-AEA3-EC377BB51CAB.1.cdt\";\n    NSUnderlyingError = \"Error Domain=UBErrorDomain Code=0 \\\"The operation couldn\\U2019t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)\\\"\";\n}";
}
2012-12-14 11:20:10.996 CloudGPSTracker[9303:907] -[_PFUbiquityRecordsImporter createSortedOperationsArrayForLogLocationsInContext:isFirstImport:](256): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Error loading comparison metadata for transaction log: (null)
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134302 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134302.)" UserInfo=0x1f5106f0 {reason=Error reading the log file at location: (null)
userInfo: (null), local error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256 - The item failed to download.)" UserInfo=0x1f50b7e0 {NSURL=file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8EEB401B-05C5-4221-AEA3-EC377BB51CAB.1.cdt, NSUnderlyingError=0x1f50b850 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)", NSDescription=The item failed to download.}
userInfo: {
    NSDescription = "The item failed to download.";
    NSURL = "file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8EEB401B-05C5-4221-AEA3-EC377BB51CAB.1.cdt";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=UBErrorDomain Code=0 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)\"";
}}
 User Info: {
    reason = "Error reading the log file at location: (null)\nuserInfo: (null), local error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 256 - The item failed to download.)\" UserInfo=0x1f50b7e0 {NSURL=file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8EEB401B-05C5-4221-AEA3-EC377BB51CAB.1.cdt, NSUnderlyingError=0x1f50b850 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)\", NSDescription=The item failed to download.}\nuserInfo: {\n    NSDescription = \"The item failed to download.\";\n    NSURL = \"file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8EEB401B-05C5-4221-AEA3-EC377BB51CAB.1.cdt\";\n    NSUnderlyingError = \"Error Domain=UBErrorDomain Code=0 \\\"The operation couldn\\U2019t be completed. (UBErrorDomain error 0.)\\\"\";\n}";
}
2012-12-14 11:20:45.173 CloudGPSTracker[9303:907] -[_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation processObjects:withState:andImportContext:outError:](845): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation: 0x20979220>:
    localPeerID: mobile.00857B2E-B835-504A-8FD6-C666D92AD889
    logScore: <PFUbiquityKnowledgeVector: 0x2096eb70> (mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14:1)
transactionLog: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x20893c90>
    transactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1f190a20>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8F59A23C-CEB2-4B0B-A663-1616726A5F77.1.cdt
    transactionNumber: 2934


 Unable to find relationship destination object: <PFUbiquityGlobalObjectID: 0x1dd44d50> (3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker:POINT:p2718:mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14)
2012-12-14 11:20:45.174 CloudGPSTracker[9303:907] -[_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation processObjects:withState:andImportContext:outError:](845): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation: 0x20979220>:
    localPeerID: mobile.00857B2E-B835-504A-8FD6-C666D92AD889
    logScore: <PFUbiquityKnowledgeVector: 0x2096eb70> (mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14:1)
transactionLog: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x20893c90>
    transactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1f190a20>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8F59A23C-CEB2-4B0B-A663-1616726A5F77.1.cdt
    transactionNumber: 2934


 Unable to find relationship destination object: <PFUbiquityGlobalObjectID: 0x1dd44be0> (3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker:POINT:p2771:mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14)
2012-12-14 11:20:45.176 CloudGPSTracker[9303:907] -[_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation processObjects:withState:andImportContext:outError:](845): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation: 0x20979220>:
    localPeerID: mobile.00857B2E-B835-504A-8FD6-C666D92AD889
    logScore: <PFUbiquityKnowledgeVector: 0x2096eb70> (mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14:1)
transactionLog: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x20893c90>
    transactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1f190a20>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8F59A23C-CEB2-4B0B-A663-1616726A5F77.1.cdt
    transactionNumber: 2934


 Unable to find relationship destination object: <PFUbiquityGlobalObjectID: 0x1dd44a60> (3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker:POINT:p2695:mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14)
2012-12-14 11:20:45.177 CloudGPSTracker[9303:907] -[_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation processObjects:withState:andImportContext:outError:](845): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation: 0x20979220>:
    localPeerID: mobile.00857B2E-B835-504A-8FD6-C666D92AD889
    logScore: <PFUbiquityKnowledgeVector: 0x2096eb70> (mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14:1)
transactionLog: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x20893c90>
    transactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1f190a20>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8F59A23C-CEB2-4B0B-A663-1616726A5F77.1.cdt
    transactionNumber: 2934


 Unable to find relationship destination object: <PFUbiquityGlobalObjectID: 0x1dd44960> (3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker:POINT:p2620:mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14)
2012-12-14 11:20:45.179 CloudGPSTracker[9303:907] -[_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation processObjects:withState:andImportContext:outError:](845): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation: 0x20979220>:
    localPeerID: mobile.00857B2E-B835-504A-8FD6-C666D92AD889
    logScore: <PFUbiquityKnowledgeVector: 0x2096eb70> (mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14:1)
transactionLog: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x20893c90>
    transactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1f190a20>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8F59A23C-CEB2-4B0B-A663-1616726A5F77.1.cdt
    transactionNumber: 2934


 Unable to find relationship destination object: <PFUbiquityGlobalObjectID: 0x1dd447e0> (3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker:POINT:p2614:mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14)
2012-12-14 11:20:45.180 CloudGPSTracker[9303:907] -[_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation processObjects:withState:andImportContext:outError:](845): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation: 0x20979220>:
    localPeerID: mobile.00857B2E-B835-504A-8FD6-C666D92AD889
    logScore: <PFUbiquityKnowledgeVector: 0x2096eb70> (mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14:1)
transactionLog: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x20893c90>
    transactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1f190a20>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8F59A23C-CEB2-4B0B-A663-1616726A5F77.1.cdt
    transactionNumber: 2934


 Unable to find relationship destination object: <PFUbiquityGlobalObjectID: 0x1dd44680> (3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker:POINT:p2715:mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14)
2012-12-14 11:20:45.181 CloudGPSTracker[9303:907] -[_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation processObjects:withState:andImportContext:outError:](845): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation: 0x20979220>:
    localPeerID: mobile.00857B2E-B835-504A-8FD6-C666D92AD889
    logScore: <PFUbiquityKnowledgeVector: 0x2096eb70> (mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14:1)
transactionLog: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x20893c90>
    transactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1f190a20>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8F59A23C-CEB2-4B0B-A663-1616726A5F77.1.cdt
    transactionNumber: 2934


 Unable to find relationship destination object: <PFUbiquityGlobalObjectID: 0x1dd44500> (3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker:POINT:p2688:mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14)
2012-12-14 11:20:45.183 CloudGPSTracker[9303:907] -[_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation processObjects:withState:andImportContext:outError:](845): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation: 0x20979220>:
    localPeerID: mobile.00857B2E-B835-504A-8FD6-C666D92AD889
    logScore: <PFUbiquityKnowledgeVector: 0x2096eb70> (mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14:1)
transactionLog: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x20893c90>
    transactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1f190a20>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8F59A23C-CEB2-4B0B-A663-1616726A5F77.1.cdt
    transactionNumber: 2934


 Unable to find relationship destination object: <PFUbiquityGlobalObjectID: 0x1dd443c0> (3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker:POINT:p2617:mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14)
2012-12-14 11:20:45.185 CloudGPSTracker[9303:907] -[_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation processObjects:withState:andImportContext:outError:](845): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation: 0x20979220>:
    localPeerID: mobile.00857B2E-B835-504A-8FD6-C666D92AD889
    logScore: <PFUbiquityKnowledgeVector: 0x2096eb70> (mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14:1)
transactionLog: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x20893c90>
    transactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1f190a20>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/3F7NTNZ29A~com~3bsoft~CloudGPSTracker/Logs/mobile.B9FC1B68-3090-52E4-905D-BBDC71020D14/3F7NTNZ29A.com.3bsoft.CloudGPSTracker/ViY1iUzbKktwTFRopnBhAMma63MPeM1zqnkmJnh39V4=/8F59A23C-CEB2-4B0B-A663-1616726A5F77.1.cdt
    transactionNumber: 2934
```

Comment: I have a similar issue with "Unable to find relationship destination object", were you able to find a cause for this error and, maybe, a solution?

Comment: i think the original database is corrupted ( lacking parent for some relationships ), so that trying to upgrade it complains for some missing records. You should check tour relationships and in particual how deletion are propagated , in any case if there are orphan records in that instance, you will go on seeing the warnings

Comment: Thanks! I see this messages logged on device 1 when I've added a NSManagedObject on device 2 and it is attempting to sync it, but in some cases (let's say 3 out of 10) for some reasons the sync doesn't go through on device 1. This is driving me crazy. Thanks again

Comment: Anyone found a solution to this problem? I am experiencing the same issue. When I want to sync lots of items just some of them are synced between device A and B